# How do I access counter in a nested foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, nested, doparallel

So, till date I have written only a handful of R codes (2 projects to be precise), which probably might justify the extent of dumbness in this question that would appear to a seasoned programmer.

I am trying to parallelise my K fold cross validation code, which aims to find the best set of variables to use for final model.

The code is somewhat like this

```
child <- foreach(i=icount(ncol(parentModel)-1),.combine = 'rbind') %:%{
  childModel<-parentModel
  childModel[,i]<-NULL
  filteredTestMTM <-foreach(j = icount(nFolds),.combine = c, .export =    c("DataSplit","getProbabilityThreshold","SharpeRatio")) %dopar% {
    splitData <- DataSplit(childModel, nFolds = nFolds, testFold=j)
    testData<-splitData$testData
    trainingData<-splitData$trainingData
    trainingMTM <- trainingData[,ncol(trainingData)]
    testMTM <- testData[,ncol(testData)]
    Trade <- (trainingMTM > 0.001)*1.0   #mtmThreshold to be used here instead of 0.001
    trainingData <- trainingData[,1:(ncol(trainingData)-1),drop=FALSE]
    trainingData <- cbind(trainingData, Trade)

    logmodel <- glm(Trade ~ .,data=trainingData, family = "binomial"(link="logit") )
    trainingData <- trainingData[,1:(ncol(trainingData)-1),drop=FALSE]
    trainingResults <- predict(logmodel, newdata=trainingData, type="response")
    probabilityThreshold <- getProbabilityThreshold(trainingResults, trainingMTM, 0.001)   #new Probability function to be defined to use optimParam
    tR <- predict(logmodel, newdata=testData, type="response")
    tMTM <- testMTM * ((tR>probabilityThreshold)*1.0)

    return(tMTM)
  }

  totalSharpe <- (mean(filteredTestMTM)/sd(filteredTestMTM))

  if (is.nan(totalSharpe)) {
    totalSharpe = 0.0
  }

  return(c(totalSharpe,i ))
}
```

In summary - I take the parentModel, one by one remove the variables, run K fold cross validation, and collect results. However I keep getting the error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = NULL) : 
object 'i' not found
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Edit : I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're not using the nesting operator, `%:%`, correctly. You have to use it with a form such as:

```
foreach(...) %:%
  foreach(...) %dopar% {
    ..
  }
```

You can't use curly braces after `%:%` to include additional operations before and after the inner foreach loop.

I suggest you change your code to:

```
foreach(...) %dopar% {
  childModel<-parentModel
  childModel[,i]<-NULL
  filteredTestMTM <- foreach(...) %do% {
    ...
  }
  totalSharpe <- (mean(filteredTestMTM)/sd(filteredTestMTM))
  if (is.nan(totalSharpe)) {
    totalSharpe = 0.0
  }
  return(c(totalSharpe,i ))
}
```

Note that the inner foreach loop is sequential, which avoids problems associated with nested parallel loops. Parallelizing only the outer loop usually leads to good results and is much simpler. I would only bother with nested parallelism if the outer loop doesn't have enough iterations to make use of all of your cores.

Comment: I have tried parallelizing only a single loop before, parallelizing the outer loop gave better results than with the inner loop parallelization. I just wanted to check if the nested parallelization would do even better.

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with paralleisation you have to make sure that the variables you need are sort of available to your cores ("environments").
you can achieve this via commands like `force(i)` - for more details have a look at e.g. this http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/parallel-computing-in-r/