# How to access an iteration counter in the first nested foreach loop?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a code to fill a big matrix by smaller submatrices using parallel computing. But I obtain this error message:

```
Error in foreach(i = j:K, .combine = "c", .packages = "geosphere", .options.snow = list(progress = iteration_progress),  :    object 'j' not found
```

Here is the code:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(parallel)
library(doSNOW)

## Create a dataset
N = 100
data <- data.frame(long = runif(N, min = -130, max = -60), lat = runif(N, min = 16, max = 60))
## head(data)

cutBySize <- function(m, blockSize, nb = ceiling(m / blockSize)) {
  int <- m / nb
  upper <- round(1:nb * int)
  lower <- c(1, upper[-nb] + 1)
  size <- c(upper[1], diff(upper))
  cbind(lower, upper, size)
}

index_sequence <- function(limits) {
  seq(limits[1], limits[2])
}

## Create the big matrix
n <- nrow(data)
mat <- big.matrix(n, n, backingfile = "test_1.bk", descriptorfile = "test_1.desc")

## Create the intervals
intervals <- cutBySize(n, blockSize = 5)
K <- nrow(intervals)

## Fill the big matrix by small submatrices
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 2, outfile = "")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
iteration_progress <- function(n){cat(sprintf("Task %d out of %d completed\n", n, K))}

test <- foreach(j = 1:K, .combine = 'c') %:%
  foreach(i = j:K, .combine = 'c', .packages = "geosphere", .options.snow = list(progress = iteration_progress), .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
    block_j <- index_sequence(intervals[j, ])
    block_i <- index_sequence(intervals[i, ])
    tmp <- geosphere::distm(data[block_i, c('long', 'lat')], data[block_j, c('long', 'lat')])
    mat[block_i, block_j] <- tmp
    mat[block_j, block_i] <- t(tmp)
  }
stopCluster(cl)
```

So, how can I access an iteration counter in the first nested loop ? I found this post [How do I access counter in a nested foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900842/how-do-i-access-counter-in-a-nested-foreach-loop) but this don’t resolve my problem.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to require a number of packages to be loaded in order to run. You should include the `library()` calls to make the example reproducible. There's also a lot of complexity here that seems unlikely to be required to reproduce the issue. Have you tried a simpler example to narrow down possible culprits?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the packages

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce the issue now.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Unfortunately, I have always the same error message. First, I've copied remotes::install_github("RevolutionAnalytics/foreach#42") and next, I have re-installed the package "foreach" with library(foreach)

Comment: Did you restart your R session after installing the fixed branch? I can't reproduce your error with the updated package.

Comment: I have restarted my R session and now this works. Thanks very much for your help ! Did you have this error message: Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection ?

Comment: I think you can fix the latter error by using `bigmemory::attach.big.matrix()` inside the `%dopar%` after saving a `bigmemory::describe(mat)` result in the global environment. But this is of course wildly off-topic from the original question.

Comment: Fantastic ! The code works now. Thanks to your help, I was able to successfully resolve my issue. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the foreach package. I have [reported it](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/foreach/issues/41) and proposed a fix which you can install with `remotes::install_github("RevolutionAnalytics/foreach#42")`.